# Why my list is empty when I am parsing correct json response?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am trying to print the ids from a JSON response. But I am not able to understand why I am getting a blank list. I have verified the JSONpath (SECTIONS_IDS_JSONPATH) from the online website and it is giving me correct results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String SECTIONS_IDS_JSONPATH = "$.[*].instructionEvents[*].sectionId";
    String sectionsData = "{\"sections\":[{\"id\":\"8da1cf5d-3150-4e11-b2af-338d1df20475\",\"courseId\":\"e8a65581-ed1c-43f0-90a7-7b9d51b35062\",\"courseCredits\":[{\"minimum\":4,\"maximum\":null,\"measure\":\"hour\",\"increment\":null}],\"academicPeriodId\":\"8b7a8e9e-5417-42a3-9c90-8d47226b5987\",\"reservedSeatsMaximum\":0,\"maxEnrollment\":0,\"hours\":[],\"sites\":[\"All Campuses\"],\"instructors\":[],\"instructionEvents\":[{\"id\":\"9d0c49e2-1579-43c3-b25a-2f85f551e62d\",\"sectionId\":\"8da1cf5d-3150-4e11-b2af-338d1df20475\",\"courseId\":\"e8a65581-ed1c-43f0-90a7-7b9d51b35062\",\"days\":[\"monday\",\"wednesday\",\"friday\"],\"startTm\":\"2019-01-01T09:45:00-05:00\",\"endTm\":\"2024-12-01T10:45:00-05:00\",\"localizations\":[],\"instructionalMethod\":\"Lecture\"}]},{\"id\":\"ad3f63ad-e642-4938-a9fd-318afd2d1ad0\",\"courseId\":\"e8a65581-ed1c-43f0-90a7-7b9d51b35062\",\"courseCredits\":[{\"minimum\":4,\"maximum\":null,\"measure\":\"hour\",\"increment\":null}],\"academicPeriodId\":\"8b7a8e9e-5417-42a3-9c90-8d47226b5987\",\"reservedSeatsMaximum\":0,\"maxEnrollment\":20,\"hours\":[],\"sites\":[\"All Campuses\"],\"instructors\":[{\"id\":\"c26572de-f9c8-4623-ba6a-79997b33f1c6\",\"sectionId\":\"ad3f63ad-e642-4938-a9fd-318afd2d1ad0\",\"role\":\"primary\",\"persons\":[{\"id\":\"c1b50d79-5505-4a33-9316-b4b1f52c0ca3\",\"names\":[{\"firstName\":\"BanColoFac-1\",\"lastName\":\"CTester\",\"preferred\":true}]}]}],\"instructionEvents\":[{\"id\":\"af8fb500-29f5-4451-95d5-a11215298cd4\",\"sectionId\":\"ad3f63ad-e642-4938-a9fd-318afd2d1ad0\",\"courseId\":\"e8a65581-ed1c-43f0-90a7-7b9d51b35062\",\"days\":[\"tuesday\",\"thursday\"],\"startTm\":\"2019-01-01T10:00:00-05:00\",\"endTm\":\"2024-12-01T10:50:00-05:00\",\"localizations\":[],\"instructionalMethod\":\"Lecture\"}]},{\"id\":\"a1422391-e2b9-4bc4-907b-371fcea01d70\",\"courseId\":\"e8a65581-ed1c-43f0-90a7-7b9d51b35062\",\"courseCredits\":[{\"minimum\":4,\"maximum\":null,\"measure\":\"hour\",\"increment\":null}],\"academicPeriodId\":\"8b7a8e9e-5417-42a3-9c90-8d47226b5987\",\"reservedSeatsMaximum\":0,\"maxEnrollment\":20,\"hours\":[],\"sites\":[\"All Campuses\"],\"instructors\":[{\"id\":\"808daae1-3ec6-47ec-9af0-5392199bdf78\",\"sectionId\":\"a1422391-e2b9-4bc4-907b-371fcea01d70\",\"role\":\"primary\",\"persons\":[{\"id\":\"793cc9b3-57c7-4a2d-8984-07a1fb6834a9\",\"names\":[{\"firstName\":\"Andrew\",\"lastName\":\"Adams\",\"preferred\":true}]}]}],\"instructionEvents\":[{\"id\":\"730b4206-684d-4413-bf20-9bec5c1dc900\",\"sectionId\":\"a1422391-e2b9-4bc4-907b-371fcea01d70\",\"courseId\":\"e8a65581-ed1c-43f0-90a7-7b9d51b35062\",\"days\":[\"tuesday\",\"thursday\"],\"startTm\":\"2019-01-01T10:00:00-05:00\",\"endTm\":\"2024-12-01T10:50:00-05:00\",\"localizations\":[],\"instructionalMethod\":\"Lecture\"},{\"id\":\"8bc059ab-a8f8-4469-8e79-bbc71f7fa3fd\",\"sectionId\":\"a1422391-e2b9-4bc4-907b-371fcea01d70\",\"courseId\":\"e8a65581-ed1c-43f0-90a7-7b9d51b35062\",\"days\":[\"monday\",\"wednesday\",\"friday\"],\"startTm\":\"2019-05-26T09:00:00-04:00\",\"endTm\":\"2021-05-26T09:50:00-04:00\",\"localizations\":[],\"instructionalMethod\":\"Lecture\"}]}]}";
    List<String> ids = JsonPath.parse(sectionsData).read(SECTIONS_IDS_JSONPATH);
    System.out.println(ids);
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is to recusively decent from the root `$..instructionEvents[*].sectionId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since this question might get delete if nothing else ever happens I better post this as an answer.

As explained by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) you should use JSONPath `$.*[*].instructionEvents[*].sectionId` instead. Quoting fromt the comment

> The syntax `$.[*]` is undefined, I can't find any documentation/example
> doing that. The JSONPath Online Evaluator [*based on
> [JSONPath-Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) implemented in JavaScript] treats it as `$..[*]`, but the Java library treats
> it differently. Since the outer part of the JSON is `{"sections":[ ... ]}`, you have an object, so you need a property selector (`.prop` or
> `.*`).    Once you've selected your property (`.sections`, or `.*`
> since there's only one), the property is an array, so you need an
> array selector (`[2]` or `[*]`). Hence you can use `$.sections[*]` or
> `$.*[*]` to match all sections.

Indeed, looking at this massive [JSONPath Comparision](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/) we can see that the syntax in question is not listed for any implementation.